# Preventing ForceDisplayMode change in a 1995 game

Tags: windows-10

I am reverse-engineering a Windows 3.1/95 [game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomorph:_Plague_of_the_Darkfall) from 1995, which changes my display resolution to 800x600 upon startup. I'd like to prevent this resolution change and run the game in windowed mode instead. However, I haven't been able to identify where this change occurs in the code.

When I attached x32dbg to the game, I noticed that the resolution change seems to happen before the main function is even executed, more specifically in apphelp.dll. I found the following in the registry in the function that does the resolution change.

```
edx:L"__COMPAT_LAYER=HighDpiAware", [ebx+8]:L"ForceDisplayMode"
```

I would like to understand why Windows decided to use ForceDisplayMode with 800x600 and how I can prevent that from happening.

Comment: May be on-topic at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidPostill Could you consider reopening it? The fact that I am reversing engineering is not relevant. I am trying to understand a specific Windows behaviour.

Comment: Will reopen, but as it's Windows 3.1/95 I don't think you will get an answer here.

Comment: You might get an answer here.. I USED TO understand how that mechanism worked but the 80s were good to me and I no longer remember.

Comment: Might be that it is a [DOS executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe) rather than a [Windows PE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) executable and so Windows assumes that it should try and run it in a graphics mode that it supports...

Comment: I worked at a game company back in those days an we indeed had code that triggered this behavior.  I just can't for the life of me remember what that was.  In NT4, it was ALWAYS windowed but in Win9x we could control this.

Comment: If you want to run it windowed and it is a DOS executable, would something like DOSBox be an option?

Comment: @Mokubai It's a PE executable, it uses wing32 for the rendering.

Comment: Running in a VM will effectively set it as windowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update the PE headers

I found the solution to the issue, which involves updating the executable's PE headers to a newer version of Windows. I tried different combinations, and using Windows 8 values (version 6.2) was the only one that worked. Here are the detailed steps:

Here are the steps:

- Download and install a PE editor, such as [CFF explorer](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388)
- Open the executable file in the PE editor.
- Navigate to the "Optional Header" section to modify the following fields:

  - MajorOperatingSystemVersion -> 6
  - MinorOperatingSystemVersion -> 2
  - MajorSubsystemVersion -> 6
  - MinorSubsystemVersion -> 2
- Save it

Note: Using Windows 7 values still causes the application to resize, while Windows 10 values result in a crash. Updating the PE headers to Windows 8 values (6 and 2) was the only successful combination I found.